# client.js para API Trello

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de utilizar la libreria de Trello **client.js** para usar la API de Trello en mi aplicación. En su página [Trello API Get Started](https://developers.trello.com/get-started/start-building) tienen un breve tutorial sobre como utilizarlo, sigo los pasos, obtengo mi *Application Key*, pero cuando inserto el código que me dan en mi sitio web y llamo al objeto `trello`, me da error en la consola:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: trello is not defined

He hecho un pequeño y simple código para probarlo y no funciona:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=[AppKey]"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     console.log(trello);
     });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

(Obviamente he sustituido [AppKey] por la *Application Key* que obtuve en el paso 1 del *Get Started*)

¿Alguna idea de  por qué no funciona?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trello es con mayúsculas

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(Trello);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Madre mia...menuda tontería y me estaba volviendo loco! Gracias!